# ServiceBusReceivedMessage in Azure Function returns error in DeliveryCount

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

When I try to run a newly created Azure function locally and getting a message from a ServiceBus topic I get this error:

DeliveryCount = 'mySbMsg.DeliveryCount' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

This is the code I ran:
[VS snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkLzh.png)

"ex" is not the values I am using, just changed for the snippet.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the complete code and as text (and not as a screenshot). Also tell us if your Function is an isolated Function or not.

Answer (score 0):

> DeliveryCount = 'mySbMsg.DeliveryCount' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

As per my research, I found that this exception occurs when the Delivery Count property is not set properly.

Check if the below troubleshooting steps help to fix the issue:

- Make sure that, the message is not getting locked by any other receiver when triggering the Service Bus topic.
- Make sure that, the message is not being received by the same receiver multiple times.
- Also, Check if the multiple receivers are trying to receive the message.
- Check if you are trying to receive the message after the lock got expired.
- Try to increase the *Delivery Count* and check if you are facing the same issue.

[image]

Basically, *InvalidOperationException* occurs when the requested user operation isn't allowed within the service. Check for the error details.

---

I have created a *ServiceBusTopicTrigger* function to check and it worked as expected:

***Code Snippet:***

```cs
public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> log)
        {
            _logger = log;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "mysubscription", Connection = "connection")]ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ILogger log)
        {
           
                log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {message.Body}");
            
        }
    }
```

***Output:***

[image]

***References:***

- Refer [doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions.md) to know about Service Bus exceptions.
- Found a similar issue, refer to [github](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2366).

Answer (score 0):

@Pravallika KV, Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. :)

I tried your steps, but still got the same error. When I received the message as string it worked, but not with the `ServiceBusRecievedMessage` class.

After I updated this NuGet it works with `ServiceBusRecievedMessage` class:
`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus`.